Array along curve modifier in geometry nodes, but with mesh input
Hi I want to array an object along a curve with geometry nodes, but I need to use a mesh as an input because I need to apply the modifier, which cannot be done with a curve as an input.

I tried to convert the curve to mesh and use 'mesh to points' instead of 'curve to points', but this node makes a point out of each vertex. But I need to be able to specify the number of points along the curve (mesh) and keep a constant offset.
Another question, but less important is how to make the instanced objects perpendicular to another object? (I separated the input geometry from this object)
My objective is to create object along the plane and boolean the created objects by geometry nodes out.

And here is the blend file


What to you mean by "how to make the instanced objects perpendicular to another object ? " ? Do you want the instanced objects to be perpendicular to the input curve, or to an other object (and if so, which one) ?

The curve is recovered from the object so if the objects were perpendicular to one it would be perpendicular to both.

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
You can recover a curve using a Mesh To Curve node from the input mesh. Then just proceed as if the input were a curve. To apply the modifier, you need also a Realize Instances node before outputting the mesh.
The Tangent output socket of the Curve to Points node returns a vector that can be used to align one axis (X in the following picture) of the instanced object to the curve. So the other axes are perpendicular to the curve.


Awesome! That makes the modifier applicable precisely as I need thanks! Any idea about the perpendicularity of the individual objects?

I documented how to align the instanced objects.
